# How can I mass rename the all pdfs in Google Docs via API

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api

In my Google Docs I have 100s of PDFs but they have underscore separating the words in filename. Now is it possible to rename them on the Google server via API and replace all underscores with space( ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These may help

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html#ListDocs
Here you can find how to go over all documents.

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html#UpdatingMetadata
Here you can find how to update the document name.